# Plotting multiple datasets of different lengths on the same scatter graph in Excel 2010 (extended)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I would like to plot multiple datasets of different length on the same scatter graph. This question was already answered exactly here:

[Plotting multiple datasets of different lengths on the same scatter graph in Excel 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/820242/plotting-multiple-datasets-of-different-lengths-on-the-same-scatter-graph-in-exc)

However, in my situation I have 200 series, each of different length, rather than just 2 so I was wondering if there is an easy way to solve this problem rather than repeatedly copying and pasting. I could use VBA but I was looking for alternatives.

Many thanks

Comment: you want to plot 200 series on one chart?

Comment: just pick the largest length and use that. If a particular series isn't the same length it just won't plot anything for the empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the different series under each other, with the X's in the same column, but the Y in consequtive columns, Excel interprets the data exactly as you describe.

Dependent on the way your original data is organized, there are several options to automatically arrange your data this way.

Here is my example, with 2 data series (random x's and sin(x) for series 1 and x^3/100 for series 2).

[image: Two dataseries in a scatterplot]